# Showing $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{g(x-n)}{2^n}$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{g(x-n)}{2^n}$$ where $g$ is a uniformly continuous function such that the series converges for each $x$.

We need to show that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. Can any one just tell me in which way I should try? From the definition I guess it will be bit clumsy.

Comment: What is the function $g$?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal $g$ is uniformly continuous, in my original post it was there.

Comment: @Kuttus: Sorry about my mis-edit. I fixed it.

Comment: @mixedmath :) ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

You can proceed using only the definition of uniform continuity. In addition, I might want to add that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{A}{2^n} = A$.